# Как правильно подружить веб-формы с custom_mail битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Такая проблема, в init.php прописана функция

```php
function custom_mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers, $additional_parameters) {
    /** @bxnolanginspection */
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitrix/php_interface/class/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    if (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') === 'development') {
        $mail = configurePHPMailer(
            'localhost',
            1025
        );
        Debug::writeToFile('MailHog', __FILE__ . '!!!', '/odegov.log');
    }
    else {
        $mail = configurePHPMailer('mail.site.ru', 465);
    }

    $toArray = explode(',', $to);
    foreach ($toArray as $t) {
        $mail->AddAddress(trim($t));
    }

    if (!empty($additional_parameters) && mb_strpos($additional_parameters, 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR') !== false) {
        $mail->AddStringAttachment($additional_parameters, 'Добавить событие в календарь.ics', 'base64',
            'text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST');
    }

    /* 2018-05-03 добавление обработки для полей BCC, CC */
    preg_match_all('/(.+): (.+)\n/i', $additional_headers . "\r\n", $matches);
    if (is_array($matches[1]) && is_array($matches[2])) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $param) {
            $upper = strtoupper($param);
            $value = trim($matches[2][$key]);
            if ($upper === 'BCC') {
                foreach (explode(',', $value) as $item) {
                    $mail->addBCC($item);
                }
            }
            else if ($upper === 'CC') {
                foreach (explode(',', $value) as $item) {
                    $mail->addCC($item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    AddMessage2Log(
        'body: ' . $message . PHP_EOL
    );
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->Sender = 'web@site.ru';
    $mail->FromName = Заголовок';
    $mail->From = 'web@site.ru';

    $headers = explode("\n", $additional_headers);
    $attachHeader = 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=';
    $alternateHeader = 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=';
    foreach ($headers as $h) {
        if (stripos($h, $attachHeader) === 0) {
            $bndr = substr($h, strlen($attachHeader));
            $bndr = trim($bndr, '"');
            $mail->ContentType = 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $bndr . '"';
        }
        elseif (stripos($h, $alternateHeader) === 0) {
            Mail::processingMessage($mail);
        }
    }
    if (!$result = $mail->Send()) {
        AddMessage2Log(
            'Ошибка отправки: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . PHP_EOL
        );


        $mail = configurePHPMailer('mail2.site.ru', 465, $mail);
        $result = $mail->Send();
        if (!$result) {
            AddMessage2Log(
                'Ошибка отправки2: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . PHP_EOL

            );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Проблема в том что, когда идет запись через веб-формы, то почта не отправляется вообще никому (ни тому кто заполнил, ни администратору сайта)
через sql стоят SUCCESS_EXEC F, проверил все стандартные методы, помогает только удаление данной функции, но как я понял smtp тогда отключается и всё идёт в спам. А остальные формы которые не через веб-форму стабильно идут. Как мне записать так чтобы и при оформлении веб-формы письма тоже летали

Answer (score 0):

Одна из стандартных ошибок при отправке почты - использовать переменную окружения $_SERVER. Когда отправка почты идёт через cron, такая переменная окружения отсутствует. Поэтому, добавляем в начало функции:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])){
    $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../..");
}
```

Почему идут остальные, не веб-формы? Могу предположить, что для них отправка почты идёт через CEvent::SendImmediate().